# Why moderator closing question? Why not cast close vote?

Tags: discussion

No offense. Some moderators here close questions with one vote. But why don't just cast a close vote? This feels power abuse!

Answer (score 9):

A single close vote from a moderator does close the question, the only way a moderator can be one vote of five is to wait until four other users have cast their votes. The moderators on this site are very reasonable reopening questions when a coherent case is made to do so.

This power isn't only restricted to moderators. A single duplicate vote from a (high-rep) gold badge user can close any questions with tags that user has the badge for.

Answer (score 4):

We are elected precisely to have this power. There's some discussion that moderators should have the *ability* to cast a non-binding vote in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41333/132930) but regardless of that, there are plenty of situations where it's appropriate for moderators to take unilateral action.

In most cases if we close a question and the community undoes it then we will accept that.